# Looking for a Morphology Database

Tags: morphology, computational-linguistics, resource-request

This is my first StackExchange post, so please let me know if I need to add additional information.

I am looking for a comprehensive database that has words broken down by their morphology. For example, the word 'protected' would be 'pro', 'tect', and 'ed'.  Similarly having would be 'have' and 'ing'.  In each case the prefixes, roots, and suffixes would be identified.

Does anyone know of a resource, preferably, open-source that would serve this purpose?  I'd like to be able to use this resource to feed into teaching activities.

FYI, between me and my friends we should be able to handle any programming needs if we need to tweak things.

Comment: Is this going to be about English only?

Answer (score 5):

CELEX certainly has this information (at shallow and deep levels of morphological analysis). It is not free. I wasn't able to find a free alternative in a quick search.

There are also morphological analysis tools for building this database yourself, though it's an area of active research. You might start by trying the resources here (http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English). NLTK does not appear to do morph analysis out of the box, but further exploration there may also be useful.

Incidentally, pro+tect+ed is unlikely to be the right parse, because 'tect' is not an English morph (though it is in the Latin source).